# Attempted import error: 'Navbar' is not exported from '@/components/Navbar' (imported as 'Navbar')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, layout

I want to add navbar and footer to my nextjs project but I unable to use layout. Here is my file structure.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
import './globals.css'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

import {Navbar} from '@/components/Navbar'
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <Navbar />
      {/* hello */}
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

And I am encountering an error:

```
Attempted import error: 'Navbar' is not exported from '@/components/Navbar' (imported as 'Navbar').

Import trace for requested module:
./src/app/layout.js
Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at layout.js:15.
- error node_modules\next\dist\compiled\react-server-dom-webpack\cjs\react-server-dom-webpack-server.edge.development.js (1684:8) @ attemptResolveElement
- error Error: Unsupported Server Component type: undefined
    at stringify (<anonymous>)
```

help me to fix this

Comment: Can you show the code of `components/Navbar`?

Answer (score 0):

You most likely forgot to `export default` your Navbar function inside Navbar.tsx

Also the Navbar component should be inside of the `body`.